# How to rearrange UITableView with custom cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with custom cells. The cells are filled with my data.
Now I want to enable the user to rearrange the rows. I have implemented the methods, but while dragging to reorder the cell, I can see it shows like it is trying to do but cannot move anywhere. It moves like 10 pixel as if it will do the rearrange but goes back to its position. How to reorder the rows with custom cell?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)  
    {
       [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    if (self.mytableView.editing) 
    {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;  
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath 
{
    id stringToMove = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

    [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

    [self.dataSource insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath 
{
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section) 
    {
            return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: You should seriously work on your code indentation!

Comment: the code indentation was fine in xcode as soon as copied here, it got messed up. so any idea why rearranging doenst happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but I will still answer it. The issue here is with your `tableView: targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath: toProposedIndexPath:` method (your last method)

Your logic is preventing any moving from happening. Your if-statement:

```
if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section)
```

is saying **if the desired location** (the location the user wants to bring the cell) **is not my current location, then return my current location** (so do not move the cell). Otherwise, **if my desired location** (the new location I want to go) **is my current location then return the desired location (which is actually my current location)**.

I hope that makes sense, so basically you are saying that no matter what, make sure every cell always remains in its current location. To fix this, either remove this method (this is not needed unless there are moves that are illegal) or switch your two return statements, so:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
      toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {

    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section) {
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
    }
    return sourceIndexPath;
}
```

In fact, the only method required to allow re-arranging is: `tableView: moveRowAtIndexPath: toIndexPath:`. So again, unless you want specific behavior out of the other methods you can save some code and just remove most of them (especially since in this situation you are mainly just implementing the defaults).